# Sublinear algorithm / find the last of distinct elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, complexity-theory

Background in case you care, if not skip it:

I was recording some audio today for a project, doing it a paragraph at a time. If I messed up the paragraph, I redid it until I got it right, and then moved on the next paragraph. When I loaded them onto the computer, I needed to find the last recording for each paragraph. Without any knowledge of the number of recordings I made for a particular paragraph, how do I go about this? (Don't you love it when algorithms sneak up into your daily life?)

In algorithms terms, you have an array of elements, where each element is either followed by another element of the same type, or a completely different element. Find each last element of the sequence (the audio clip correctly recorded).

**The problem:**

So you have an array of objects where each element with an id field, where each id is in the following list. I want the objects that are the last of their id, say in array of id's like this:

```
aabbbbbccddddddddddddddeefffffffffggghhhhiiiijjklmnnnnoo
```

Obviously if the length of the string is n and there are n distinct elements, it will take you n steps to figure it out. I'm more interested in the general algorithm. I could do it with a binary search type algorithm, but I don't know the runtime of it in the case with no knowledge of the input except the number of total elements.

Also, would knowing the number of distinct id's change the runtime of the algorithm? This is an interesting problem to me and I'm asking to only satisfy my intellectual curiosity.

Comment: Can you tell from two different ID's whether or not there is an id in between?

Comment: nope, unless you know the total number of ID's and you've seen enough to pigeonhole sections. this is more a pure thought question, the requirements of the problem are malleable.

Comment: Your example of n distinct elements proves that no general algorithm can guarantee performance better than O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to look at the first id, and do a binary search for where that id ends. This can be done in *O(log n)* time.

You then step forward to the next element, and redo the binary search for where that id-sequence ends.

This yields an algorithm of complexity *O(m × log n)* where *n* is the number of elements and *m* the number of distinct elements.

Assuming *n / m* (the average number of elements for a specific id) is greater than *log n* you get a sub-linear algorithm.

If *n / m* is less than *log n* you are better of searching for the end of the id-sequence linearly.

(Note that this whole analysis depends on the fact that the list is sorted on the IDs. Sorting typically takes time proportional to *n × log n* so if you need to sort them, you can just as well go with a linear algorithm :-)

Comment: In your example, I think you mean if n / m is greater than logn you get a sublinear algorithm ie m*logn < n

Comment: Ah, well spotted. I got it backwards. Thanks!

Comment: Also I believe finding when the ID ends can be done in O(logm) time by looking 2 elements away, 4 elements away, ... 2^k elements away until you get a new element. Then you do a binary search to find the last element. This will be O(logm). So your algorithm would be O(mlogm) which like you said is only good if mlogm < n I suppose.

Comment: Hmm... that's smarter! But *m* in this case is the number of distinct ids, and not, the number of elements witd a particular id. Perhaps O(log(n/m)) would be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Get first and last elements in the array and analyze middle element in this range. If new `id` is found, put last element to the stack (with `id` and its range of positions found so far). Otherwise continue binary search in the range between the lowest and the middle element. When one last distinct element is found, pop the stack and continue search.

Time complexity is `O(m * log(n/m))`, space complexity is `log(m)`. Where `m` is the number of distinct values.

Comment: Is there any important difference between this answer and aioobe's?

Comment: This algorithm is faster than in aioobe's answer. It has the same complexity as in Sean Nilan's comment, but works differently and probably is a little bit faster (does not need separate search for the next ID).

Answer (score 0):

A variant to a "classical" binary search is not to split the whole space, but to grow geometrically. That is, if you are at position *p*, try to look at *p*+1, *p*+3, *p*+7, *p*+15, ..., until you find an interval where there is a change to new id, and there you can either split it by classic binary search, or even start the new growing again at the last known good position.

Complexity is probably the same as ones before, that is O(*m**log *n*), but this may be better suited to your problem, since the runs of the same ids are presumed to be relatively short (around *n* / *m*).

Answer (score -1):

A binary search runs in time proportional to log(n). That means that the more elements you add, the slower it grows. More precisely, an exponential growth in the problem size means a linear growth in the execution time. In other words, every time you double the number of recordings you have, you need to take another listen in order to find what you want.

In order to do a binary search you would start in the middle of your list of recordings and figure out if the recording you want is before or after it, you then discard the half that does not contain it. If the recording is the right paragraph (but you do not know if it is good or bad), then group it with the after and discard all the recordings before it. Continue eliminating half (by listening to the middle one) until you are down to 1 or 2 recordings.

Comment: I'm not looking for a particular recording, I'm looking for all last recordings with a distinct element.